# ExtJS not receiving response from POST

Tags: c#, javascript, html, extjs

When I type the URL http ://localhost/login/login.aspx into my browser, I see my response is {success: true}.  When I run my load my html page, I can see from Fiddler and the debugger that the aspx page is called; however, nothing is being returned to my javascript and it go to FAILURE instead of SUCCESS.

I have used this url in other programming projects, but this is my first time using it with Ext JS. I have seen various examples online and none seem to fix my issue. Below is my javascript file and any help would be appreciated in getting a successful return on my button click.

So, it is not entering my C# code from the javascript call even thought fiddler shows the call is being made to http ://localhost/login/login.aspx.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.window.Window'
]);

Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var field = new Ext.form.field.Text({
        renderTo: document.body
    }),
        fieldHeight = field.getHeight(),
        padding = 5,
        remainingHeight;

    field.destroy();

    remainingHeight = padding + fieldHeight * 2;

    var login = new Ext.form.Panel({
        border: false,
        fieldDefaults: {
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 100
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        bodyPadding: padding,

        items: [{
            xtype: 'box',
            region: 'west',
            width: 128,
            height: 46,
            autoEl: { tag: 'img', src: 'images/logo.png' },
            style: 'margin: 10px 0px 15px 15px'
        }, {
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Company Name',
            name: 'company',
            emptyText: 'Company ID',
            style: 'margin: 10px 0px 10px 30px'
        }, {
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel: 'User ID',
            name: 'user',
            emptyText: 'User Name',
            style: 'margin: 10px 0px 10px 30px'
        }, {
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'pass',
            emptyText: 'Password',
            inputType: 'password',
            style: 'margin: 10px 0px 10px 30px'
        }]
    });

    new Ext.window.Window({
        autoShow: true,
        title: 'Support Tools Login',
        resizable: false,
        closable: false,
        width: 350,
        height: 250,
        layout: 'fit',
        plain: true,
        items: login,
        constrain: true,
        draggable: false,

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
            formBind: true,

            handler: function () {
                login.getForm().submit({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/login/login.aspx',
                    waitTitle: 'Connectiong',
                    waitMsg: 'Sending data...',

                    success: function (login, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success');
                    },

                    failure: function (login, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure')
                    }
                });
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Aspx file:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using SupportToolsCommon;

namespace App.login
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static Database db;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write("{success: true}");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

default.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <!-- ExtJS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/support-tools.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/login.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="login-page"></body>

</html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
Response.Write("{success: true}");
```

with well formed JSON (property names must all be enclosed in quotes in JSON, as opposed to javascript):

```
Response.Write("{\"success\": true}");
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but it is still returning as a failure.  So far the only success I have seen was from http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/84CPU/.  I even tried using the echo url from jsfiddle to echo the response to my code and it failed also.  http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/

Comment: You can't submit your form to jsFiddle because, as I've said, you **must** submit to an URL on the same domain. Can you see the error message in the console, there: http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/84CPU/2/? You are affirmative that you don't get such an error in the code you're debugging, aren't you?

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot.  Thank you for taking the time to spell it out for me.  I don't know why the cross-domain issue was not sinking into my head.  Of course...now that I am calling everything from localhost, it works perfect now.  Thanks again for your patience!